# Show/Hide td values that match an input value jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html table with a status column which can have text value of "approved", "rejected", etc. I want to match the status column to an input value from a selected radio input. For each row, if the text in the status column matches the selected radio input, show the row; otherwise, hide it. For example, if `input[type="radio"]` value is  "LATE", show all the rows whose status td text is "LATE" and hide the other rows.

```js
 
       var val = $(".radio:checked").val();
                    $('.table tbody tr').each(function () {
                        var latevalues = $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(6).text()) === val;
                        if (latevalues === val) {
                            $(this).parent().toggle();
                        }           
                    });

 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">                   
                    <!-- <form> -->
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="pending" value="LATE" checked="checked">
                            Pending(Default)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="approve" value="A">
                            Approved
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="Rejected" value="R">
                            Rejected
                        </label>
                    </div>                                         
                </div>                
            </div>
            
            <table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">

 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Comments</th>           
            <th>Submit</th>
            <th>Occassionent</th>
            <th>Review</th>
            <th>Status</th>  -----> column to match values          
            <th>Admin</th>
            <th>By</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Managers Status</th>        
             
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
   <tr>
                <td>
                        <a href="employees>
                            <span>49656</span>
                            <span> - </span>
                            <span> 24 May 2021</span>                           
                        </a>
                </td>

                <td>                    
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div> Due:</div>
                    <div> 24 May 2021</div>
                    <div> Act:</div>
                    <div> <b class="danger">9 Apr 2023</b></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div> Due:</div>
                    <div> 16 Apr 2023</div>
                    <div> Act:</div>
                    <div> <span>9 Apr 2023</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div><b class="success">LATE</b></div>---------->Status column Show this status if matches the input boxes
                </td>

                    <td>
                        <div>
                                <dl>
                                     
                                        <dd>Joe Anthony</dd>
                                </dl>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 90px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 70px;">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            
           <tr>
                <td>
                        <a href="employees>
                            <span>49656</span>
                            <span> - </span>
                            <span> 24 May 2021</span>                           
                        </a>
                </td>

                <td>                    
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div> Due:</div>
                    <div> 24 May 2021</div>
                    <div> Act:</div>
                    <div> <b class="danger">9 Apr 2023</b></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div> Due:</div>
                    <div> 16 Apr 2023</div>
                    <div> Act:</div>
                    <div> <span>9 Apr 2023</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div><b class="success">A</b></div>---------->Status column Show this status if matches the input boxes
                </td>

                    <td>
                        <div>
                                <dl>
                                     
                                        <dd>Joe Anthony</dd>
                                </dl>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 90px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 70px;">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            
             <tr>
                <td>
                        <a href="employees>
                            <span>49656</span>
                            <span> - </span>
                            <span> 24 May 2021</span>                           
                        </a>
                </td>

                <td>                    
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div> Due:</div>
                    <div> 24 May 2021</div>
                    <div> Act:</div>
                    <div> <b class="danger">9 Apr 2023</b></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 90px;">
                    <div> Due:</div>
                    <div> 16 Apr 2023</div>
                    <div> Act:</div>
                    <div> <span>9 Apr 2023</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <div><b class="success">R</b></div>----------> Status column Show this status if matches the input boxes
                </td>

                    <td>
                        <div>
                                <dl>
                                     
                                        <dd>Mark Anthony</dd>
                                </dl>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 90px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 80px;">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 70px;">
                    </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, jQuery's [.eq method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) is *zero-based*, so to get the sixth `<td>` in the row you need to use `.eq(5)` (`.eq(0) would get the first` `).

Next, you have an extra comparison. You assign to the variable `latevalues` the boolean result of comparing the text in each `<td>` for equality with the selected radio value. You then take that boolean result and compare that with the selected radio value: `if (latevalues === val)`. This will always return false.

Furthermore, your radio values are of inconsistent cases (uppercase, lowercase, etc.). I would recommend lower-casing the selected radio value and the text values it is compared with to make the matching effectively case-insensitive.

The corrected code:

```js
const updateState = () => {
  const filterStatus = ($(".radio:checked").val() || '').toLowerCase();

  $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
    const rowStatus = ($.trim($(this).find('td').eq(5).text()) || '').toLowerCase();
    
    $(this).toggle(rowStatus === filterStatus);
  });
};

$('input[name="radio"]').on('change', updateState);

updateState();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <!-- <form> -->
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="pending" value="LATE" checked="checked">
        Pending(Default)
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="approve" value="A">
        Approved
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" id="Rejected" value="R">
        Rejected
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Submit</th>
      <th>Occassionent</th>
      <th>Review</th>
      <th>Status</th> -----> column to match values
      <th>Admin</th>
      <th>By</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Managers Status</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="employees">
          <span>49656</span>
          <span> - </span>
          <span> 24 May 2021</span>
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div> Due:</div>
        <div> 24 May 2021</div>
        <div> Act:</div>
        <div> <b class=" danger">9 Apr 2023</b></div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div> Due:</div>
        <div> 16 Apr 2023</div>
        <div> Act:</div>
        <div> <span>9 Apr 2023</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div><b class="success">A</b></div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div>
          <dl>

            <dd>Joe Anthony</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90px;">
      </td>
      <td style="width: 80px;">
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70px;">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="employees">
          <span>49656</span>
          <span> - </span>
          <span> 24 May 2021</span>
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div> Due:</div>
        <div> 24 May 2021</div>
        <div> Act:</div>
        <div> <b class=" danger">9 Apr 2023</b></div>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90px;">
        <div> Due:</div>
        <div> 16 Apr 2023</div>
        <div> Act:</div>
        <div> <span>9 Apr 2023</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div><b class="success">R</b></div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div>
          <dl>

            <dd>Mark Anthony</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 90px;">
      </td>
      <td style="width: 80px;">
      </td>
      <td style="width: 70px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi I made a mistake and make the question answered too quick.  $(this).toggle(rowStatus === filterStatus); is showing only the <thead> headers only. The actual matched rows are not showing up

Comment: @edward678: Are you sure you have matching rows? The code snippet in my response is showing the matched rows (although there are no matches for "Pending" state). If your actual row data is different than what is in the question, can you update what is in the question?

Comment: There is a match row for LATE and Approved. So when Approved checkbox is check I want to show only the approved state

Comment: @edward678: I don't see "LATE" appear anywhere in your table.

Comment: The LATE value is for pending state

Comment: Give me a minute

Comment: I have edited the code. pending(Default) is just a label for the input value LATE, Approved is a label for A, and Rejected is a label for R

Comment: Are you using the label as the state or the value?

Comment: @edward678: That's fine. I have updated my snippet to use "A" and "R" instead of "approved" and "rejected".

Comment: Thanks. I will update with the results soon

Comment: Did you change anything in your jquery and do you have a fiddle for me to see because it still showing on the headers only

Comment: @edward678: I can put it in a fiddle, but it is the same code as is in the attached code snippet. Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/cwvj4n1k/

Comment: @edward678: Click the radio inputs to see the filtered rows change.

Comment: I see your fiddle is working correctly so let me check what I am missing here

Comment: I see why it is not working on my end. Because of the pending

Comment: How do I get the pending work with the LATE

Comment: @edward678: It would need to have the text "LATE" in the status column. If you need different matching logic, you need to supply that information.

Comment: It does have LATE. See my updated HTML and see if I am missing something

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly with LATE. Thanks

Comment: Let me get it into my code and update you soon

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm. I will appreciate.

Comment: @edward678: You are very welcome. I would appreciate an up-vote on this post.